# logback.xml versus gradle build

Tags: gradle

Since gradle is using slf4j (and logback as backend) I was hoping/assuming to change log format of gradle using the commonly used "-Dlogback.configurationFile=_path_to_logback.xml_". However, it seems to be ignored by gradle.

Questions arise:

1. Is this supposed to be (not) working ?
2. Is there another (un)documented way to change log format ? I am aware of the -q, -i, -d flags, but those are not really what I'm looking for.

In fact: what I wanted to achieve is to show timestamps in the standard gradle logging; gives some handy information ico long-running builds.

Environment:

Gradle 2.1 / JVM : 1.7.0_45 (Oracle Corporation 24.45-b08) / OS : Windows 7 6.1 amd64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Gradle 2.1, changing the Gradle log format isn't supported. (I don't know of any unofficial way either.)

Comment: OK, that's a clear statement; any plans to make it somehow configurable (again) in the future, or is it really a firm and deliberate intent not to allow it anymore ?

Comment: It wasn't ever configurable, and I don't know of any concrete plans to make it configurable (although I think it would be useful).

Comment: (Not surprisingly) I also think it would be a useful addition. I'm currently evaluating migration from maven to gradle; some months ago, I tuned the maven logging (ref: http://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html) to give some more valuable info. It's a pity gradle does not allow this. For the rest, I'm not complaining ;-) Would it make sense to request this as a (low prio) gradle feature ?

Comment: It's likely that there already is such a feature request. You can check at http://issues.gradle.org.

Comment: (as suggested at http://issues.gradle.org/) I created a feature request on the gradle forum: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/logback-xml-versus-gradle-build